# Бесконечный вызов lifecycle методов React компонента

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Задача: делать редирект на компонент логина с любой страницы, если пользователь не залогинен.
Проблема: при редиректе с главной страницы на страницу логина в консоли ошибка - **Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тестовый код:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, BrowserRouter, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

import Main from './components/Main';
import Auth from './components/Auth';
import Providers from './components/Providers';

import configureStore from './store/index';

var store = configureStore();

store.subscribe(() => {
  var state = store.getState();

  console.log(state);
});

var fakeAuth = {
  isAuthenticated: false
};

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: {from: props.location}
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter basename="/admin">
      <div>
        <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Main} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Auth} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

При этом редирект с любого другого урла работает нормально. Например, если заменить `<PrivateRoute path="/" component={Main} />` на `<PrivateRoute path="/protected" component={Main} />`. В это случае все ок, так как редирект идет с protecterd URL.

Почему беда при редиректе с главной? Постоянно вызываются componentDidUpdate и componentWillUpdate компонента Auth.

Компонент Auth:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Auth extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>You must log in</p>
        <button>Log in</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: А в компоненте Auth случайно в  методе componentWillUpdate не осуществляешь вызов setState?

Comment: Нет. Там вообще только метод render для теста

Comment: хмм ... ну в таком случае надо ставить брейкпойны и дебажить, посмотреть стек вызовов и откуда ноги растут у ошибки

Comment: А на Auth бы посмотреть

Comment: Добавил в описание

Comment: Закинул решение кейса очень похожего на вас. А вообще это одинаково верно и для редиректа и для push у Роутера. Если вместо редиректа проверять onEnter авторизацию и рушить изнутри компонента, результаты будут схожими

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что роут `/` является префиксом для `/login`, а потому при редиректе на `/login` активируется снова первый роут.

Используйте `exact` чтобы проверить полное совпадение а не совпадение по префиксу:

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Main} />
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!!!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Main} />
> <Route path="/login" component={Auth} />
> ```

Первый роут перехватывает всё и получается бесконечный редирект.

Надо либо дописать ему атрибут exact, чтобы компонент работал только с корнем

```
<PrivateRoute path="/" exact component={Main} />
<Route path="/login" component={Auth} />
```

либо поменять роуты местами, чтобы логин срабатывал до всего остального:

```
<Route path="/login" component={Auth} />
<PrivateRoute path="/" component={Main} />
```